# Merge Cells on TemplateProcesscor PHPWord

Tags: php, laravel, phpword

I have table in my template in TemplateProcessor PHPWord. I want to ask if I can merge the cells using TemplateProcessor? In the documentation, there is only cloneRow() method and such merge cell method.

Here is the illustration
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/nu1yl.jpg)

Thank you